# What is the German word for sales man?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, single-word-request

I know there is one translation and that is *Kaufmann*. That is more for a grocery store.

I am wondering are there any names for a person who sells products to customers that are other buisnesses?

Example a company that sells programs for a POS system.

Comment: Put that as an answer. :)

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. Many dictionaries (e.g. [this dictionary](https://www.dict.cc/?s=salesman) will give you a choice of different translations of *salesman* to German. I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. To get a good answer let me suggest you [edit] your question to give us more details and narrow the context.

Comment: ... as well as Vertriebler, Verkäufer, Kundenbetreuer, Key Account Manager, Koofmich, and many others. It really depends on the industry and context. - By the way, what is a POS system?

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, point of sale nehme ich an. Wahrscheinlich eine Kasse ;)

Comment: try to make clear: do you want all meanings of "Kaufmann"? as Janka already showed: there are multiple definitions. Or do you want a german translation for a special sales man? a sales man has multiple tasks to do and each task may be specified with another word (/translation)

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong with your assumption *Kaufmann* means someone who works in/for a grocery store. It's the common name for a grocery store.

But **Kaufmann** is also the name of a skilled trade, and there are many many specialized apprenticeships of that kind, all with that word in it. There's also the **eingetragener Kaufmann**, which is a law term for a single-person trade firm with some special properties. And of course, there's also the **Kauffrau**.

A company – more than one person – in contrary is a **Gesellschaft**. That's the law term but it's also used in common language. A **Handelsgesellschaft** is a company which trades goods. Same with **Vertriebsgesellschaft**. If it sells to the general public, it becomes a **Einzelhandelsgesellschaft**. (Same with the **Einzelhandelskaufmann**.)

There's no special name for a company that sells to companies only (or mostly). **Großhandel** exists, but that's more a class than a name. No one writes *Großhandelsgesellschaft*.

You can also simply write **Händler** for someone who trades, a person or a company:

> Ihr Händler für Point-of-Sale-Systeme
>
> Ihr Großhändler für Point-of-Sale-Systeme

You may want to use **Ausstatter** for someone who sells appliances.

> Ihr Ausstatter für Point-of-Sale-Systeme

*Your supplier for point-of-sale systems.*

Answer (score 2):

*Verkäufer* scheint mir die naheliegende Lösung zu sein.

Answer (score 0):

> Vertreter, Vertriebsmitarbeiter (corresponding to *sales representative*, *sales employee*)

or

> Handlungsreisender (standard translation of Arthur Millers novel)

Comment: That translation is decades old, though. No one actually says "Handlungsreisender" for a door-to-door sales man anymore, the current term is *Vertreter*.